# Error loading the module Pillow

Tags: python, anaconda

I installed `Pillow` using Anaconda but if I cannot load the module (see below). How coudl I fix this?

```
dhcp-86-216:Python_code Alberto$ pip install Pillow
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Pillow in /Users/Alberto/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...
dhcp-86-216:Python_code Alberto$ python 
Python 2.7.6 (v2.7.6:3a1db0d2747e, Nov 10 2013, 00:42:54) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import Pillow
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named Pillow
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import `PIL`, not `Pillow`:

```
import PIL
```

Comment: `dhcp-86-216:Python_code Alberto$ pip install PIL
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): PIL in /Users/Alberto/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL
Cleaning up...
dhcp-86-216:Python_code Alberto$ python 
Python 2.7.6 (v2.7.6:3a1db0d2747e, Nov 10 2013, 00:42:54) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PIL
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named PIL`

Comment: Pillow is a fork of PIL (see https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.3.1). The name of the package has changed, but the name of the library you import (and assumedly most of the API) has not changed. This allows you to hot-swap the original PIL and Pillow without modifying your code.